# CKEditor: create a new object from a parent object

Tags: object, ckeditor

A question about creating a new object within an object.

Say that you edit a query created with CKEditor, and that query is stored as an object. In that query, you identify a part of the text, and from that part, you want to create a new object which is supposed to live within its parent object, but also be independent.

Example:

query obj starts here:

text ...
more text ... (this represents the new object that I want to create)
end text...

query obj ends here.

example html when you edit an existing query created with CKeditor:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="para">
<p>This represents a citation that should become an object.<p>
</div>
</div> <-- end #wrapper -->
```

The newly created object remains in the old object (old object is an article, say), but the new object receives its own tags and link.

Can this be done; if so, how? :-)

Comment: Please provide an example of the actual HTML you are trying to create. Your question and example are not clear.

Comment: Done. Let me know if I can be any clearer. Not sure others can visualize what I have in mind.

Comment: I think you'll achieve what you want by writing a ckeditor widget. Take a look at the [official tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1) (read both parts).